# How can i fit RelativeLayout to screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am facing with problem button shows outside the screen in `RelativeLayout`. `ImageView` doesn't o scale picture to give a button visible place.

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"  >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorTertiary"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

<ru.mw.widget.DrawableImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/processButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
```

Problem when I change screen orientation:
If I use [**Arun C Thomas**'s  method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16054342/989433) in landscape mode everything is ok, but in portrait mode I have this (image cropped by left/right edges):

[image]
What is expected:

[image]

Comment: Add android:alignParentBottom to your button, and android:alignParentTop (both  = true) to your Textview. You're not setting any boundries at the moment for your ImageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"  >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorTertiary"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

<ru.mw.widget.DrawableImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_above="@+id/processButton"
     />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/processButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the solution

Now to achieve  the **Updated** requirement add the above layout to `layout-land` folder in `res` (if you don't have one create a folder named `layout-land` in `res` ) now in default `layout` folder add this xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center"  >
<ru.mw.widget.DrawableImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/processButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/str" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/str"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorTertiary" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thats it.

Comment: I hoped this could achieved with one layout, but your are right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/processButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/str"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Align the button to parent bottom using
   `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.
2. Wrap the `ImageView` between the `TextView` and `Button`

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"  >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorTertiary"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/processButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

<ru.mw.widget.DrawableImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/processButton"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```